# ValueError under pynput/keyboard/_base.py while executing a script

Tags: python, valueerror, pynput

I am creating a script using pynput. I installed pynput on my Raspberry Pi using the command "sudo pip3 install pynput". When I try to run my script, it stops at the first space and then displays an error message.

I have tried checking pynput with "sudo pip3 check pynput", but it only says "thonny-pi 1.1 requires python3-thonny, which is not installed.". I have no idea where thonny came from, as I am trying to check pynput.

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/MyScript.py", line 11, in <module>
    keyboard.press("space")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/_base.py", line 357, in press
    resolved = self._resolve(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/_base.py", line 550, in _resolve
    raise ValueError(key)
ValueError: space
```

My script is, when whittled down:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

import time

time.sleep(5)

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(".")

keyboard.release(".")

keyboard.press("b")

keyboard.release("b")

keyboard.press("space")

keyboard.release("space")

keyboard.press("m")

keyboard.release("m")
```

Comment: use `Key.space`

Answer (score 0):

The pynput module uses a class named pynput.keyboard.Key which assigns all the keys that are not in the alphabetical or numerical range.  The space bar falls under this class which makes it not possible to use with the value of a string.  The class assigns all of these strings as 0 unless you use the class.  To use the space bar type:

```
keyboard.press(Key.space)
```